# How to multiply the value of a textview while the button is incremented?

Tags: java, android, button

I am currently on working on a project on firebase and I was wondering how to multiply the value while the button is incremented. For example, I have this image

[image]

In this image, if I clicked the + button the Number of Orders will be 1 and it will keep increasing until I clicked the - button. On the bottom of it, there is the value which is 1.00. For every time the button is clicked for example it will become 1 it will also multiply the textview which is 1.00. Then if button is incremented it will be 2x1.00 which is 2.00.

This is the code I have done so far

```
public class Detailsoforder extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "AddToDatabase";
private static int click = 0;

private TextView titles;
private TextView increase;
private TextView Price;
private int count = 0;

//add Firebase
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailsoforder);

    titles = findViewById(R.id.Order);
    increase = findViewById(R.id.Increase);
    Price = findViewById(R.id.Price);
    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

    titles.setText(title);
    Price.setText(price);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };

    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG,"Value is"+value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void onIncreaseClick(View view) {

    String price = Price.getText().toString();
    int result = Integer.parseInt(price);
    count++;
    increase.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    Price.setText(String.valueOf(count*result));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
  Button plus = findViewById(R.id.plus);
  plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // for orders numbers
       int number = Integer.parseInt(ordersTextView.getText().toString().trim());
       number = number+1;
       ordersTextView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
      // for total cost 
       Float cost =  Float.parseFloat(costTextView.getText().toString().trim())*number;
       costTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cost));
    }
});
```

Comment: For decreasing, what should I put on it?

Comment: For decreasing you just replace   number = number+1; by   number = number-1;

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't hvae to use count vaariable and anything else you can do this directly with the text view like this example.

Set text to your textview 0 by default then get this text on click of + button and add 1 in this and again set the value to the text view

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setText("0");

Button plus = findViewById(R.id.plus);
plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           int number = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString().trim());
           number = number+1;
           textView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        }
    });
```

Now in this way you can set the incremented value to your text view please check if it will work and then ask me if need any other help.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: Will this be able to multiply the value? which is 1.00?

Comment: Yeah sure and if it will not work then tell me we will find another way to do this.

Comment: Yes if we want then we can multiply the value too just have to change the line 
number = number * 1

Comment: Hmm I Don't know if I'm doing it right but the app crashes

Comment: Will you show the error which you will be able to see in the logs so that i can better understand this.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem has been solved now. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Welcome  So just like my answer